# Avoiding Null value in Odata query

Tags: filter, odata, expand

In OData V4, I am trying to expand an object (which is an array) and filter based on if the array object is empty.
eg :
Request

```
ODataService/v1/ODataServiceName.svc/v1/ABCRevisions?$expand=Status
```

Response

```
{
"@odata.context": "ODataService/v1/ODataServiceName.svc/v1/$metadata#ABCRevisions(Status())",
"value": [
    {
        "Revision": "A",
        "Identifier": "032103",
        "Status": [
            {
                "type": "Status",
                "Name": "Approved"
            },
            {
                "type": "Status",
                "Name": "Released"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Revision": "A",
        "Identifier": "032097",
        "Status": []
    }]}
```

Basically, I want to filter response where "Status" is **not** empty

I tried the following it-

a.    `ODataService/v1/ODataServiceName.svc/v1/ABCRevisions?$expand=Status($filter=Name ne null)`
This approach didn't work

b. `ODataService/v1/ODataServiceName.svc/v1/ABCRevisions?$expand=Status/$Order`
which gave me the status count but didn't filter the response accordingly
Response -

```
{
"@odata.context": "ODataService/v1/ODataServiceName.svc/v1/$metadata#ABCRevisions(Status())",
"value": [
    {
        "Revision": "A",
        "Identifier": "032103",
        "Status@odata.count": 2        
    },
    {
        "Revision": "A",
        "Identifier": "032097",
        "Status@odata.count": 0
    }]}
```

Can someone tell me how to filter Object where status is not empty?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `any` in `$filter` query to return only entities with at least one status.

```
ODataService/v1/ODataServiceName.svc/v1/ABCRevisions?$expand=Status&$filter=Status/any()
```

or check if count is not equal to 0

```
ODataService/v1/ODataServiceName.svc/v1/ABCRevisions?$expand=Status&$filter=Status/$count ne 0
```